# Close Bootstrap's Navbar on click on a handlebars link

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, handlebars.js

I would like to close automaticaly the responsive bootstrap navbar menu when the user click on an item of the menu. These links are made with handlebars. I've written this code but it doesn't work :

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Contacts Management</a>
    </div>
      <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li>{{#link-to 'index' data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"}}Accueil{{/link-to}}</li>
          <li>{{#link-to 'about' data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"}}A propos{{/link-to}}</li>
          <li>{{#link-to 'contacts' data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"}}Mes contacts{{/link-to}}</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

If I use the html tag `<a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">Accueil</a>` instead of the `{{#link-to ...}}`, it works but I need the handlebars tags.

Could you help me ? Is there a solution without javascript ?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I've found the solution. I create a view to bind the data-toggle and data-target attributes :

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.View.extend({
});

Ember.LinkView.reopen({
  attributeBindings: ['data-toggle', 'data-target']
});
```

The solution is explain on the docmentation of Ember.js : http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/templates/binding-element-attributes/